# How to receive file or images using MQTT and ESP8266

Tags: github, mqtt, raspberry-pi4, arduino-esp8266

I  am developing a ESP8266 based project that will be able to communicate with MQTT server (publish and subscribe) ,I'll also need to make files  receives  from MQTT server .
It is possible to do this with ESP8266 and MQTT ?.I had searched on Google and  but I didn't get very clear answers. Can anyone suggest be better solution?

Comment: What is the software you run for the MQTT "server"? or you means MQTT broker? like mosquitto or some online broker?

Comment: MQTT message payloads are just a collection of bytes, you can publish anything you want, how you interpret what those bytes represent is totally up to you. It is possible to send something that represents a file, but you will have to work out how to encode the metadata (e.g. file name...)

Comment: Please make sure you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what questions should container

Comment: @hcheung
 i am using mosquitto server

Comment: mosquitto is a mqtt broker, which just passing your MQTT messages around between the publisher and the subscriber(s). To convert the message to a file and save it somewhere, you need a subscriber to subscribe to a topic (i.e. a mqtt client) and do the work to convert the message to appropriate FS format to save it to the file system of a computer.